# Android NDK how to pass received DatagramPacket as arguments to the C function?

Tags: android, c++, c, sockets, android-ndk

I am receiving DatagramPacket in my android application from a C Program. I need to use NDK to parse the data. I want to pass the received packets to the native method to parse. Could someone tell me a way to pass the received packet to the C function?

```
 DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
 socket.receive(packet);
 System.out.println(packet.getLength());
```

Now I need to pass this received packets to the C function to parse.

Comment: You want to pass the received datagram packets to the C oprogram you got them from? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to pass the received datagram packets to the native method within Android. Not back to the C program which I received from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `buf` (assuming it's a `byte[]`) and the value of `packet.getLength()` to the JNI function. Inside that, use byte array functions - e. g. `JNIEnv::GetByteArrayRegion()` to get the actual bytes.

Comment: The C function is already defined to receive the packet. I am receiving a structure _PktHdrTypeDef as byte[] and the C function is void Parse_header(_PktHdrTypeDef * pPktHdr)

Comment: You know arbitrary C functions cannot be called from Java anyway, right? You would need a JNI compliant wrapper for that, in the form `Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_MyMethod()`.

Comment: In that case can I pass the packet as MyMethod(buf) and receive it as Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_MyMethod(JNIEnv * env, _PktHdrTypeDef * pPktHdr)

Comment: No. If you pass a `byte []` from the Java side, the JNI side will receive a `jbyteArray` and nothing else. It's up to you to retrieve the bytes from the array. Also, the size of the received packet might be less than the length of the buffer; you will want actual packet size.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what does `_PktHdrTypeDef` stand for. Whatever that data structure is, it's up to you to populate it.

Comment: Thanks Seva Alekseyev... I am able to receive the byte array using GetByteArrayRegion(). I am accepting your answer!!